# Input tipo file abrir ao carregar página

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho o seguinte input:

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera" style="display:none" id="capturar">
```

Gostaria que ao carregar a página já abrisse o campo para selecionar o arquivo.
Tentei o seguinte, em jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("#capturar").click();
});
```

Porém sem resultado.
Alguma ajuda ?

Comment: Já tentou substituir por `$("#capturar").trigger('click');` ? Em algumas versões específicas [de navegadores] o `.click()` não funciona.

Comment: Sim, mesmo assim não abre o campo de selecionar o arquivo

Comment: @PedroAugusto por segurança é pouco provável, provavelmente impossível, isso que tu está pedindo, que no caso é ativar um `input type="file"` sem o evento click.

Comment: [Aqui](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/210643/in-javascript-can-i-make-a-click-event-fire-programmatically-for-a-file-input) tem varias respostas explicando o porque você não irá conseguir fazer isto!